# How to gracefully shutdown jetty in intelliJ idea 13?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetty, embedded-jetty

intelliJ idea 13 come with a jetty integration plugin, which can active jetty modules & run jetty's start.jar.

but when using this plugin to development, i found there is no way to shutdown the jetty gracefully.

every time i click close button in run/debug panel, it just kill the jvm rather send stop key to jetty daemon. it is difficult to debug shutdown code in such case.

how can i shutdown jetty gracefully in intelliJ?

BTW: the intelliJ-idea's tomcat integration have no such problems(it can shutdown tomcat gracefully and my shutdown code was invoked).

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you can use "Undeploy" button instead of "Stop".
[image: Undeploy button]